# How to avoid reflection?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I have abstract class `BaseClass` with `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` implementations. The user can extend these two subclasses or use them, e.g. he creates only `UserExtensionClassA` and uses `MyClassB` as it is. There is a class `ClassC` responsible for the initialization of the classes. It receives configuration (e.g. containing the full class names of the needed implementation classes) and decides when and whether the classes are initialized (e.g. already 3 existing instances of `BaseClass` implementations => reject creation request).

Question: How can I avoid the reflection in the example? `ClassC` can create the classes from the names in the configuration. But I can still change almost everything in the library implementation and I don't like reflection stuff.

Comment: this is confusing, please post some code to clarify the situation. also, reflection seems not that bad a solution...

Comment: Please post what you have tried? Helps alot.

Comment: Why not to write the code instead of writing *"I have abstract class BaseClass with MyClassA and MyClassB implementations"*? It's not clear why and how you are using reflection (configuration is dictionary?), can you show it? As well as wanted *pseudo-code*. But in general reasons like *"I don't like reflection stuff"* aren't reasonable ones. Do you read configuration once or 1234567 times? Do you run into performance/memory issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend not running your own but relying on an existing IoC (inversion of control) container such as Autofac as this gives you a high degree of flexibility while also facilitating design concepts such as dependency injection (DI) and inversion of control (IoC)

Most IoC containers provide a programmatic interface as well as JSON/XML file-based configuration support, including [Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html):

Autofac config file example:

```
{
    "defaultAssembly": "Autofac.Example.Calculator",
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition.Add, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Addition",
            "services": [
                {
                    "type": "Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation"
                }
            ],
            "injectProperties": true
        },
        {
            "type": "Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division.Divide, Autofac.Example.Calculator.Division",
            "services": [
                {
                    "type": "Autofac.Example.Calculator.Api.IOperation"
                }
            ],
            "parameters": {
                "places": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Building the container:

```
// Add the configuration to the ConfigurationBuilder.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");

// Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(module);
```